# Solving ODE $y'=3|y|^x$ with initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the function $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto 3|y|^x$, where $G=\mathbb{R}_+ \times\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore is $y$, as in the standard notation of ODE, a function of $x$.

I should solve the initialvalue problem $y'=3|y|^x$ with $y(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{1}{27}$, but I don't have any idea how to deal with the $x$ in the exponent.
I tried yet to rewrite the equation to\begin{equation}y'=3e^{x\cdot log(|y|)}\end{equation} but this didn't help much.

Could someone provide a hint how to deal with ODEs of this type? Thanks!

P.S. This is your chance to show that human mind is superior to computational power. Wolframalpha resigns here...

Comment: @Amzoti, I don't think that the question is about how to get rid of the absolute value symbol. The question is how to solve analyticaly equation $y'=3y^{x}$

Comment: @Tomas: Thank you - too early in the morning!

Comment: Where did this ode come from?

Comment: Actually from a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an approximate solution for the ode $y'=3y^x$ at the point $x=\frac{2}{3}$

$$ y \left( x \right) = {\frac {1}{27}}+{\frac {1}{3}} \left( x-{\frac{2
}{3}} \right) + \left( 1-\frac{1}{2}\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)  \right)  \left( x
-{\frac {2}{3}} \right)^{2}+ \left( 2-3\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)+\frac{1}{2}\,
 \left( \ln  \left( 3 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right)  \left( x-{\frac {
2}{3}} \right) ^{3}+O\left(  \left( x-{\frac {2}{3}} \right) ^{4}\right). $$